# Tail recursion with a vector passed by reference

Tags: c++, recursion, pass-by-reference, tail-recursion

Consider an example of a tail recursion

```
int foo(vector<int> &vec, int n)
{
    if (n == 1) return vec[0];      
    vector<int> new_vector = createNewVector(vec);              
    return foo(new_vector, n-1);
}
```

where `createNewVector(vec)` is any function that returns new vector with the same size as `vec`.

I am worried that compiler could not detect it as a tail recursion because `vec` is passed by reference (previous stack frame cannot be deleted as the `vec` reference point to previous `new_vector`). In that case the memory used for this recursion would be `O(n*vec.size())`, since each previous stack frame contains `vec.size()` elements.

Is this true, or this function can be optimized as a tail recursion?

Comment: gcc and clang don't do tail recursion here: https://godbolt.org/g/q85ci4

Comment: Tail recursion is never guaranteed anyway. And you're right - in this case its probably impossible.

Comment: FWIW `int foo(vector<int> vec, int n)` and `return foo(createNewVector(vec), n-1);` might.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tail recursion (TCO) is impossible in this context. The `new_vector` destructor has to be called after return from recursive call, which completely eliminates any possibility for TCO.

In general, destructors for automatic objects make it very tricky for compilers to engage in TCO when automatic variables of non-trivial types are at play, and passing the vector by value or by reference in your example doesn't make a difference - TCO is still not happening.

Comment: Just to confirm. If I pass `vec` by value instead of reference than I would have tail recursion.

Comment: @Dejan, no - destructor of `std::vector<int>` still needs to be called.

Comment: Destrucor needs to be called, but as far as I know the point of tail recursion is to call that destructor before recursive call and delete previous stack frame. So, destructor would be called and it would be a tail recursion. Right?

Comment: @Dejan, no. Destructor has to be called AFTER your tail call returns.

Comment: I do not understand this. Can you please describe it better. What about parameter `n`? Is it destroyed before or after recursive call with `foo(...,n-1)`? If it is destroyed after call, than this is not a tail recursion. So, it must be destroyed before rec.call in order to be tail recursion. I think that same must apply for `vec`.

Comment: @Dejan, `n` is an integer parameter, so there is no destructor to be called for it. On the contrary, `std::vector` has a destructor - a function, which needs to be called after your recursion function returns, but before your caller function is allowed to return.